# Compute $(p-2)! \pmod p$ and $(p-3)! \pmod p$.

Tags: number-theory

I have problem solving these two problems:

Let $p > 3$ be prime. Compute

1. $(p-2)! \pmod p$
2. $(p-3)! \pmod p$

We barely went over Wilson's theorem in class which states "Let $p$ be an integer greater than one. $p$ is prime if and only if $(p-1)! = -1 \pmod p$."

I don't really know how to use Wilson's theorem to problems. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**.  Let $x=(p-2)!$.  Then $(p-1)x=(p-1)!$, so you have to solve the congruence
$$(p-1)x\equiv-1\pmod p\ .$$
Can you do this?

Similarly, if $y=(p-3)!$ then you have to solve
$$(p-2)(p-1)y\equiv-1\pmod p\ .$$

Comment: are both answers 1?

Comment: No, the first is but not the second.

Comment: can you show me how to do the second one?

Comment: Start by simplifying the LHS modulo $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$(p-1)!=(p-1)(p-2)!$$

If you can find the inverse of $p-1$ then you're done.